# How to get handle for a coverpoint?

Tags: system-verilog, function-coverage

How can I get a handle for a coverpoint so that I can call methods using that handle?
First I need to know the type of a coverpoint so that I can instantiate the handle.

Here is an example:

```
class my_coverage_class;
  rand bit my_coverpoint;
  covergroup my_covergroup;
    option.per_instance = 1;
    coverpoint my_coverpoint;
  endgroup
  function new;
    my_covergroup = new;
  endfunction
endclass: my_coverage_class

program automatic testbench;
  initial begin
    my_coverage_class inst = new();
    begin 
      var type(inst.my_covergroup.my_coverpoint) cp
        = inst.my_covergroup.my_coverpoint; // BREAKS HERE
      cp.get_inst_coverage();
    end
  end
endprogram // testbench
```

When I run the above using VCS 2013.06, I get:

```
Error-[NYI] Not Yet Implemented
testbench, 16
Feature is not yet supported: Type operator not supported
```

Note: When I run `$display("%s", $typename(inst.my_covergroup.my_coverpoint))`, I get `<unknown>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, your simulator does not yet support `type`. Even if it did, I don't see anything [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) that suggest there can be a handle to a `coverpoint`. If your simulator supports handles for `covergorups`, then you should be able to do the following:

```
package my_package;
  covergroup my_cover_group(bit cp);
    option.per_instance = 1;
    coverpoint cp;
  endgroup
  class my_coverage_class;
    rand bit my_coverpoint;
    my_cover_group my_covergroup;
    function new;
      this.my_covergroup = new(this.my_coverpoint);
    endfunction
  endclass: my_coverage_class
endpackage : my_package

program automatic testbench;
  import my_package::*;
  my_cover_group covgrp_handle;
  initial begin
    my_coverage_class inst = new();
    begin 
      covgrp_handle = inst.my_covgrp;
      covgrp_handle.cp.get_inst_coverage();
    end
  end
endprogram // testbench
```

Other options is to use a macro (ex: `` `define cp inst.my_covergroup.my_coverpoint ``). This would work for the provided test case, however it is not very flexible if intended for dealing with many (possibly unique) types of instances/covergroups/coverpoints.